# Error 508. Resource Limit Is Reached

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli, codeigniter-3

```
public function get_advertisement($userid){
    $query="SELECT *
            FROM
            advertisements
            WHERE
            advertisements.adtype =  'website'
            HAVING
            advertisements.id NOT IN  (SELECT
            work_done_ads.ad_id
            FROM
            work_done_ads
            WHERE
            work_done_ads.user_id =  '".$userid."')
            order by advertisements.id asc
            LIMIT 1";
        $result= $this->db->query($query)->row();
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT *
            FROM
            advertisements
            WHERE
            advertisements.adtype =  'website'
            HAVING
            advertisements.id NOT IN  (SELECT
            work_done_ads.ad_id
            FROM
            work_done_ads
            WHERE
            work_done_ads.user_id =  '".$userid."')
            order by advertisements.id asc
            LIMIT 1");
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
            {
                return $result;
            }
        } else {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT ad_cycle from users WHERE userid='$userid' LIMIT 1");
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
                {
                    $ad_cycle = $row["ad_cycle"];
                    $ad_cycle = $ad_cycle + 1;
                }
            }


            $this->db->query("UPDATE users SET ad_cycle=$ad_cycle WHERE userid='$userid' LIMIT 1");
            $this->db->query("DELETE FROM work_done_ads WHERE user_id='$userid'");
            $query="SELECT *
                FROM
                advertisements
                WHERE
                advertisements.adtype =  'website'
                HAVING
                advertisements.id NOT IN  (SELECT
                work_done_ads.ad_id
                FROM
                work_done_ads
                WHERE
                work_done_ads.user_id =  '".$userid."')
                order by advertisements.id asc
                LIMIT 1";
                $result= $this->db->query($query)->row();
                return $result;
        }

}
```

This query gets ads from database that have not been seen by the user yet, if a user completes all ads than views counter sets to 0 so that user can continue seeing ads and this is a cycle that continues.

this query uses too much resource that server gives 508 error, Is there any way to write this query that uses less server resources

Comment: Make sure there's an index on stuff like `work_done_ads.user_id`, for starters.

Comment: Perhaps you should narrow the problem down to a single query.

Comment: How it can be to single query